# Count distinct destinations a pattern may lead to

Tags: algorithm, grid, dynamic-programming

I recently faced a classical dynamic programming problem, but I am not sure how exactly should I construct and iterate over the states.

I have a navigational string consisting of F's, B's, L's, R's, and *'s for missing directions. I should say to how many distinct destinations the pattern may be leading assuming that in the missing places any direction may stand.

Can you help me?

Comment: not enough data to answer meaningfully

Comment: I added a little more background

Comment: THERE IS AS YET INSUFFICIENT DATA FOR A MEANINGFUL ANSWER.